# How to put call on hold via cli or ami or agi

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I tried already to use Park app in ami but the point that is always hangup the other channel for example I have this two channels

```
PJSIP/600-00000076
PJSIP/300-00000075
```

and the already bridged and I want to put `PJSIP/300-00000075` on hold and let the other channel do some stuff and then go back to `PJSIP/300-00000075`

I want to do that without any interaction from the phone just cli or ami
not I tried this (AMI)

```
Action: Park
Channel: PJSIP/300-00000075
Timeout: 0
```

but the problem is that is hangup the other channel. so how can I put one channel on hold and let other channel do his stuff and then go back to him al by cli or ami

thks for helpers I hope I was clear after all my English not so good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Redirect command and transfer BOTH legs of channels to Musiconhold or Park

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Redirect

Comment: thks it's not the same as press hold on the phone because when u press on phone it make your channel hear the tone and not the musiconhold but that solution enough for me